# Which event fires click on 'previous' or 'next' button on virtual keyboard on iPad?

Tags: html, ios, ipad, keyboard-events

Which event fires click on 'previous' or 'next' button on virtual keyboard on iPad ?

Keys on virtual keyboard would fire keydown event, but these two navigation keys would not. So, wchich event should I listen ? Note: I was working on Safari.

Comment: Did you ever get/workout an answer to your question?